# Passing Apache Camel Endpoint Uri from a Spring Property

Tags: java, xml, spring, apache-camel

I want to use my spring bean's property as uri of camel sql component's uri. But I have not found any information about this.

it is like:

```
<bean id="programBean" class="com.tcell.cms.gateway.bean.ProgramBean">
     <property name="uri" value="www.asdasa.com"/>
</bean>
```

And in Camel context:

```
<route>
    <from uril="sql:${programBean.uri}
</route>
```

I have looked at some samples but it did not work.

Any help will be appreciated

Thx

Ali

EDIT: I want to pass url of SQL Endpoint from an attribute of a bean. Not from a property file. The uri is an attribute of a bean.

Answer (score 1):

See the Camel documentation about using property placeholders.

- http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

And also this FAQ about using spring ${ } in Camel routes

- http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-use-spring-property-placeholder-with-camel-xml.html

Comment: I think I could not express myself. I want to pass a bean property into an sql endpoint url. The url should be built in a bean method at startup time.

Comment: Spring does not support that!